# Xpath query to find all elements whose attributes match those of their ancestor elements

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0

Using this example HTML:

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="one.html">One</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="one.html">One a</a></li> <!-- I want this one -->
        <li><a href="one.html">One b</a></li> <!-- I want this one -->
      </ul>    
      <ul>
        <li><a href="two.html">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="three.html">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="four.html">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="five.html">Five</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="five.html">Five a</a></li> <!-- I want this one -->
            <li><a href="five.html">Five b</a></li> <!-- I want this one -->
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

I need to match any `<li>` elements whose child `<a>` element contains the same `<href>` attribute as its parent `<li>/<a>`.

I've tried this, which doesn't work because it selects ALL of the elements (because it's matching the first `<li>` item):

```xml
//li[a[@href=ancestor::li/a/@href]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
//li[a/@href=ancestor::li[1]/a/@href]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these XPath :

```
//a[@href=//preceding-sibling::a/@href]
```

Here's my result on the Xpath Playground using above XML

[image: Xpath Playground Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks :) This is close, but it also gives me the parent elements (One and Five). I only want the children (One a, One b, Five a, Five b). I also want the entire <li>, not just the anchor